# r, stuck on converting numeric to factor with labels

Tags: r

I am stuck on this topic and I am new to R. I am trying to take this repetition pattern and assign levels using factor(), as.factor(), or levels() to assign levels to 1-5 such as 1 = yes, 2 =no, 3 =sometimes, 4 = almost never, 5 = almost always (these are for the purposes of this example only, I am aware that they do not make sense in terms of order). I am out of ideas. I have tried assigning the below code to a variable ex: x and making it as.factor(x) and then use:

```
x <- as.factor(x)
y <- factor(x, c('yes','no','sometimes','almost never', 'almost always')
#or y <-  factor(a, levels = c('yes','no','sometimes','almost never', 'almost always'), ordered = TRUE)
```

the output always gives me a bunch of NA values. I am trying to get R to convert 1-5 to the respective values  and output yes < no < sometimes ,etc... in terms of providing an intrinsic order for my values/levels

code I have for the pattern this:

```
rep(c(1:5),each=3,times=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost had it, its labels not levels

```
factor(
  rep(c(1:5),each=3,times=4),
  levels = 1:5,
  labels = c('yes','no','sometimes','almost never', 'almost always'),
  ordered = TRUE
)
```

Edit: as Roland pointed out, including both levels and labels is safer.

Comment: It's safer to always specify also the levels when you specify labels. That makes the mapping explicit.

Comment: The code in its current state produces `NA` values for me; this was after you added the `levels` parameter.

Comment: @steveb My mistake, levels should include the current values, labels the new values.

Comment: @user2974951 It works now.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help, I really appreciate it. the book I am using to learn R, I have learned on labels but only for ylab and xlab. Just wondering why my code was giving NA rather than factors?